# How to get the actual text from a span element enclosed within multiple span tags, using Selenium Webdriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium

Hi, I am new to Selenium Webdriver. Please help me in resolving this issue.

The HTML structure is following:

```
<div> "other attibutes"
    <span> "other attibutes"
        <span>  "other attibutes"
            <span> "other attibutes" Text </span>     
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Now I am writing a Java code like this:

```
public getCustomText() {
    List <WebElement> objSpanList = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_layout_ContentPane_1")).findElements(By.tagName("span"));
    for (WebElement e : objSpanList) {
        System.out.println("The element text is : "+e.getText());
    }
}
```

When I am calling this function it outputs like this:

```
 Text 

 Text

 Text
```

There is no compilation or run time error in the output.

Actually only for the last span element it is having a text, but for upper span tags it is only having the different attributes,but no element text. All the span elements are having the text of last span element. So I am confused regarding the behavior of the selenium web driver.

I am not sure whether I am getting correct output or not. Or this is the default nature of selenium web driver for a span tree as above.

So please explain to me what actually is happening here or there is some fault from my end.

Comment: Could you provide real HTML? It's difficult to visualise this with half-baked HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) - A JAVA HTML parser library for these operations. Your code works as it should be. As per the documentation,

```
 getText()
```

*returns the visible (i.e. not hidden by CSS) innerText of this element, including sub-elements, without any leading or trailing whitespace*

thus, it will return the inner text of the sub-elements. i.e. text of inner span elements. *In order to locate only the inner span element with text content, you can subclass `By` Class and override the protected methods as required, though it is expected that that all subclasses rely on the basic finding mechanisms provided through static methods of this class*

Comment: Normally Selenium Web Driver is having all the APIs to parse any sort of HTML. I just want to know the explanation of the outcome of the above pasted code. Is there any problem with the above code? Is it expected output or some thing is wrong ? Please explain me..

Comment: If I use Jsoup parser then what are the differences I will found? Is it going to return me the only text of the span element which is actually having the text? Please reply....

Comment: Generally, It's easy to use JSOUP. I see tha `getText()` returns Text. Did you check the tags are properly closed?

Comment: Yes, I do checked the tags properly here. Just tell me whether is it the inherited nature of Selenium Web driver? Or some thing is going wrong ?

Comment: So you are saying that for the upper span elements if the span elements are not having specific element text, still for them I will be getting the text, which is coming from the inner span element with respect to that upper element,where the inner element is having the specific text of it's own.

Comment: If the above description is correct then can you tell me that it is applicable for the span tags only ? Or other tags also having the same property ?

Comment: As per the doc, it means that any visible text (i.e. not hidden by css) of this element including sub-elements without any leading or trailing spaces. This really mean that it will give all visible text of it's own and other inner elements irrespective of span html tag

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Comment: Yeah,sure....Just one thing wanna know, suppose I am having a form tag and the element text is A. And a div tag is mentioned under the form tag and it's element text is B. So if I extract the text of form tag,I will be getting A and B both,right? Or I will be getting only A as text? Please clarify.......

Comment: You will be getting both A and B in getText() (if both are visible).i.e. not hidden by CSS. Please accept the answer to let others know that this question has been answered

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 `<span>` elements, one inside the other, so your output is accurate even by your own admission: "All the span elements are having the text of last span element".

You can change:

```
List <WebElement> objSpanList = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_layout_ContentPane_1")).findElements(By.tagName("span"));
```

To:

```
WebElement innerSpan = driver.findElement(By.xpath(\\div\span\span\span"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. Actually, I can't use a static xpath as u have said. The reason is I wanna generic function. I will be only passing the form object kind of thing, and then I wanna to iterate any number of span element depth. So hard coded xpath is not going to work for me here.

Comment: If u have better idea then please share me.

Comment: If u have the exact HTML (instead of just "other attributes"), then please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<WebElement> lst=driver.findElements(By.tagName("span"));
    for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++)
    {System.out.println(lst.get(i).getText());}
```